# Extracting parts of a single-file zip

Tags: c++, zip

I have a zip file which consists of a single file.  I need to use multiple processes/nodes and each one processes only a part of the zipped contents.

Let's say the decompressed data is 100MB, and it gets compressed to 60MB.

Any way to do either of these?

A) Seek into the zip file so I can extract only 1MB of decompressed data.  Then I use 100 nodes, each processing 1MB after decompression.

Or

B) Just decompress 1MB of the zip data.  Then I use 600 nodes, and they end up processing a different amount of decompressed data.

It's fine also if the split points are not 1MB, but match some other intervals (don't all have to be the same) if it would simplify implementation.  Goal is just that each node can get a different part of the data, without each node having to decompress the whole source.

Comment: I feel like partial extraction of a single file is not a thing.

Comment: Yes, I don't think the zip format allows for anything other than decompressing the whole file from beginning to end

Comment: You can't seek in a zip file.  Decompression depends on processing everything that came before - there are no 'restart points'.  (There could have been, but the format is not designed that way.)  Is there another way you can compress your data (such as several smaller zips) or are you stuck with what you have?

Comment: Stuck with what I have... this is an archive of zip files unfortunately.  I guess the least amount of work to get let's say the 20th MB, is to decompress from the start until I get 20MB of data, and discard the first 19MB.

Comment: @Warpin Indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer my question.

No.

(see comments for more info, basically with zip we have to decompress always from the start).